# Paperclip is processing attachments even when they don't pass validation?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I have a model that uses paperclips for image attachments

I currently require that the attachment be an image using a validation

```
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /^image\/(jpg|jpeg|pjpeg|png|x-png|gif)$/, :message => 'file type is not allowed (only jpeg/png/gif images)'
```

However when I try to upload a non-image I get these error messages.

```
Image /var/folders/1f/0jtzzpl56sdcb92spkx6rpch0000gn/T/10-21-201120120908-44073-j59q0s.pdf is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
Image /var/folders/1f/0jtzzpl56sdcb92spkx6rpch0000gn/T/10-21-201120120908-44073-j59q0s.pdf is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
Image content type file type is not allowed (only jpeg/png/gif images)
```

So it seems like the file is being passed to ImageMagick even though the file does not pass the validation. I want the last error message only and not the first 2.

How can I either suppress the two first messages or make sure that the file is not processed unless it passes the content type validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with

```
before_post_process :process_only_images

def process_only_images
    if !(image.content_type =~ %r{^(image|(x-)?application)/(x-png|pjpeg|jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$})
      return false 
    end
end
```

Comment: what does exactly the %r do?

Comment: it's just regular expression that tests content type

Answer (score 1):

Check out following link, you might find your solution here by adding custom method
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/paperclip-plugin/oVnIgfAfrLU

Thanks,

Nidhi Sarvaiya